# How can estimate the PSF function to deblur an image of plate licence of a car

Tags: image, convolution, image-processing

I want to deblur an image of a licence plate of a car. I have used the `ImageDeconvolve[]` function and `Sharpen[]` but the problem is still difficult because I need to estimate the kernel or the PSF function. A lot of techniques have been used to estimate the PSF. I wondered how the Fourier transform of the blurred image can give us an idea about the PSF function?

```
psfMotion[dim_?NumberQ, theta_?NumberQ] :=
  Module[{PSF},
    PSF = ConstantArray[0.0, {dim, dim}];
    PSF[[Ceiling[dim / 2.0], All]] = 1.0 / dim;
    Return[ImageRotate[Image[PSF], theta  Degree]];
   ];
psf = psfMotion[14, 0];
Table[ImageDeconvolve[licence, psfMotion[2, \[Theta]], 
  Method -> "RichardsonLucy", MaxIterations -> 15], {\[Theta], 0, 
  180}]
```

Comment: In the movies, they just say: "computer: enhance!" If that doesn't work, it would be good to provide more detail in your question, e.g., an example image and what else you have tried.

Comment: @Jens, I edited my question

Comment: Did you try anything or are you simply hoping someone's either done this before or is really bored and will do it?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2gU8E.png

Comment: @rm-rf, can you show me How did you find this please!

Comment: I enhanced it, like in Jens' suggestion :D

Comment: which algorithm did you used please?

Comment: @rm-rf, why the blind deconvolution did not work

Comment: @rm-rf, did you used a special software?

Comment: @rm-rf the licence is not true. thanks

Comment: The example image is clearly limited by the image resolution (pixelation) and not by the point spread function of the camera. So it's pretty hopeless. There is a [Wolfram Blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/27/fixing-bad-astrophotography-using-mathematica-8-and-advanced-image-deconvolution/) about this topic.

Comment: Let's enhance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhF_56SxrGk

Comment: Where is the blurred image for `licence`?